# PHPExcel Ошибка открытия файла xlsx после сохранения

Tags: phpexcel, php

С помощью PHPExcel сохраняю файл в формате xlsx. Сохраняется нормально, а вот когда хочешь открыть Excel, выдает ошибку:

> *В книге "Отчет по резервам.xlsx" обнаружено содержимое, котрое не
>   удалось прочитать. Попробовать
>   восстановить содержимое книги? Если вы
>   доверяете источнику этой книги,
>   нажмите кнопку "Да".*

Нажимаем Да - выводится сообщение:

> Была выполнена проверка на уровне
>   файла с последующим восстановлением
>   файла. Некоторые фрагменты документа
>   могли быть восстановлены либо удалены.

Генерируется XML с отчетом об ошибке:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <logFileName>error048360_01.xml</logFileName>
    <summary>Обнаружены ошибки в файле
        "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Отчет по
        временным резервам с 01.01.2015
        (6).xlsx"
    </summary>
    <additionalInfo>

        <info>Была выполнена проверка на
            уровне файла с последующим
            восстановлением файла. Некоторые
            фрагменты документа могли быть
            восстановлены либо удалены.
        </info>
    </additionalInfo>
</recoveryLog>
```

Настройки PHPExcel:

```
<?
$outputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $outputFileType);
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);

/*Сохраняем документ*/
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $nameXLS . '.xlsx');
```

Используется office 2010.

После всех сообщений отчет открывается, и всё с ним нормально, как и должно быть.
Подскажите, как избавится от этих сообщений об ошибках?

Comment:  Заменить в фале все то, что не надо на необходимые параметры. Не отключать макросы!
В файле xlsx после сохранения получите пересчет между системами координат
 http://dropmefiles.com/RXu3z

Comment: Не понял??? какие ещё такие системы координат???

Answer (score 2):

В общем, проблема решилась довольно-таки просто:

Оказалось, что нужно в коде указывать следующее сочетание:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

либо

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

У меня же было так:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

Что есть неправильно.

Comment: если данный ответ является решением Вашей проблемы, пожалуйста, отметьте его [решением](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (зеленая галка под цифрой слева от текста ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, имеет смысл порезать css перед генерацией excel. И вообще в принципе тем же самым пару дней назад занимался. Скиньте архив с исходниками и не забудьте в исходнике указать UTF-8(без BOM). [гайд](http://habrahabr.ru/post/245233/)

Comment: @anunak, этот гайд я читал. CSS при генерации файла никак не задействован.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была та же проблема, и помог этот код. После него ошибки не было.

```
mb_internal_encoding('latin1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже ругался на сгенерированный excel-файл при использовании php7. Проблему решил следующим образом:

1. Добавил в начале скрипта `mb_internal_encoding('latin1');`
2. Перед выводом файла добавил `ob_end_clean()`, так чтобы получилось:

   ```
   ob_end_clean();
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   ```
3. В файле `/PHPExcel/Calculation/Functions.php` закомментировал break в 581-й строке:

   ```
     if (($value === NULL) || (is_float($value)) || (is_int($value))) {
       return 1;
     } elseif(is_bool($value)) {
       return 4;
     } elseif(is_array($value)) {
       return 64;
       //break; - php7 ругается, комментируем
     } elseif(is_string($value)) {
       //   Errors
       if ((strlen($value) > 0) && ($value{0} == '#')) {
         return 16;
       }
       return 2;
     }
     return 0;
   }    //  function TYPE()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема (правда, с модулем PHP Excel Templator, но он работает на основе PHPExcel), перебрал все вышепредложенные способы -  ничего не помогло, ошибка так и возникала. Экспериментальным методом подобрал решение:

1. Перенес генерацию .xlsx-файла в отдельный php-скрипт (до этого генерация происходила в том же файле, что и форма ввода данных для пользователя)
2. Скопировал текст шаблона в свежесозданный файл с сохранением форматирования.

Теперь все ок.

Answer (score -1):

мучился с той же проблемой
помог модуль импорта экспорта opencart
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17
методом втыка подобрал решение
в конце надо добавить exit;

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpexcel, 'Excel2007');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="products.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
$objWriter->save('php://output');

//без этой строки при открытии файла xlsx ошибка!!!!!!
exit;
```

причем с xls такой проблемы нет

может кто прокомментирует потому что мозгов не хватает

Comment: Дело в том, что у вас записывается, что-то еще после отправки файла. И это попадало в содержимое файла. Если вы пишите exit, то тем самым убиваете возможность продолжения работы скрипта и его корректного завершения. Не совсем элегантное решение.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше замечание. Действительно работа скрипта обрывается. Что и требуется после отправки данных в ://output чтобы не было дополнительного вывода. Спасибо за подсказку. Хотя в чем именно не элегантность решения не понимаю.

Comment: Но ведь вместо того, чтобы разобраться, что такое у вас записывается в поток, вы просто убиваете скрипт. Это может привести к дополнительным ошибкам в дальнейшем и/или с другими скриптами, + если вы захотите написать какой-нибудь обработчик для данного метода, чтобы он выполнял что-либо после этой функции, или реагировал на удачное/не удачное завершение, то вы не сможете этого реализовать.